# How can I send properly an oauth 1.0 request to verify credentials with nodejs

Tags: node.js, oauth, twitter-oauth

I have a problem I am trying to debug and I would appreciate some help.

The oauthToken variable and the oauth_token in the curl command as well as the consumer keys are identical.

This curl command works:

```
curl --get 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_crn: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="dv5trHvHDrAjIM87Z3KGtJrq5", oauth_nonce="7aec4b5b37ab420d44717387e2f889be", oauth_signature="qm4i0jGOPbbmYkaOFCoJhOfgcd4%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1443690396", oauth_token="71611055-pzDi5UJQXKzdP4kBLceLLwuzel8DKiRjNivlmkCuA", oauth_version="1.0"' --verbose
```

The following two don't and they have supposedly the same params. They return

> 401 - {"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}

First try is with https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#oauth-signing

```
      const oauth={
        consumer_key:config.get('twitter.consumerKey'),
        token:oauthToken,
      }
      console.log(oauth);

      requestAsync({
        url:'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json',
        method:'GET',
        oauth,
      })
```

Second try is with https://github.com/ciaranj/node-oauth

```
  const oauthToken=req.body.accessToken.split(':')[0];
  const oauthTokenSecret=req.body.accessToken.split(':')[1];
  console.log(oauthToken+" " + oauthTokenSecret);
  const oauth = new OAuth.OAuth(
    'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',
    'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token',
    config.get('twitter.consumerKey'),
    config.get('twitter.consumerSecret'),
    '1.0A',
    null,
    'HMAC-SHA1'
  );

  oauth.get(
  'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json',
  oauthToken,
  oauthTokenSecret,
  function (e, data, res){
    if (e) console.error(e);
    console.log(require('util').inspect(data));
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [request docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#oauth-signing) there are 4 required OAuth parameters that you have to supply:

```
request({
  oauth: {
    consumer_key: '...',
    consumer_secret: '...',
    token: '...',
    token_secret: '...'
  }
})
```

You can get the `consumer_key` and the `consumer_secret` from your OAuth application's settings page. The user's `token` and `token_secret` can be obtained through executing the OAuth flow.

You can use [Grant](https://github.com/simov/grant) to get the user's credentials. You can check out how the OAuth flow for Twitter looks like [here](https://grant-oauth.herokuapp.com/#/twitter).

Comment: you don't need the secrets for the verify credentials https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials there is a demo where you get the curl command which is generated from the official twitter page and works in my command prompt.

Also in the second example I am using the secrets for both the consumer and user.

Comment: Did you even tried my solution? I know the answer, because it works on my end. The secrets are used to calculate the signature. Also I strongly suggest you to use request instead of node-oauth.

Comment: I will accept your answer, I didn't realize the secrets are used to calculate the signature but not present in the curl command and thank you. The second example didn't work because the access_token retrived by twitter has the form token:secret@consumer_key and I didn't strip the @

Comment: If you are curious how exactly the OAuth spec is implemented in request, check out [here](https://github.com/request/request/blob/master/lib/oauth.js) (notice where the secrets are being deleted, they are used only for signing the request).